# Valid provisioning profile not found for device

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, provisioning-profile

I just got an iPad Air 2. I want to test my app on this iPad device. In Certificates, identifiers and profiles, I registered the UDID of the device. In provisioning profile, I added this device and the status is Active. However, it's not active and managed by Xcode. How do I make it active and managed by Xcode status?

Answer (score 1):

Some time Xcode  doesn't load the generated provision profiles So, you can do it manually by,

Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> (select your account) -> View Details -> refresh (left bottom corner)

And if you see the provision profile in the list then you are good to go.!

Note: Don't forget to choose the related acc in

Target -> General -> Team (dropdown list)